# Getting an error message COMPLETE NAND_WRITE_FAIL while trying to flash galaxy R via Odin I9000

Tags: rom-flashing, odin

I tried to flash the samsung galaxy R device but build transfer was successful but at the end i got the above message. Also, unlike normal odin, it has flash lock option. I think Nand_write_fail was occurred because my device could flash locked. Can you help it unlock?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unlock as in network unlock? - head to the nearest phone unlocking shop or go to your carrier and ask them to get it unlocked.

Comment: I'd rather guess bootloader-lock?

Comment: yeah, i am talking about bootloader flash lock.